# Is it ok, that Range iterates through Fixnums but #last returns Float?

Tags: ruby, type-conversion

Working on my code, found that I lose the floating point somewhere. It turned out that inside my function, when I do `.each` on `Range`, it iterates though `Fixnum`s:

```
> (1..4.0).each{ |i| p [i, i.class] }
[1, Fixnum]
[2, Fixnum]
[3, Fixnum]
[4, Fixnum]
```

While `.last` says it is `Float`:

```
> (1..4.0).last
=> 4.0
> (1..4.0).last.class
=> Float
```

Had no luck forcing iteration through `Float`s in this way:

```
> (1.0..4.0).each{ |i| p i }
TypeError: can't iterate from Float
```

**So two questions are:**
1. Does this all mean, that I have to iterate via own iterative loops instead of using Range if I want to work with `Float`s?
2. Is the above behavior the same through all Ruby implementations? (not just universal.x86_64-darwin13)

Answer (score 1):

`Range#each` starts at the first object in a range and calls #succ until the iterated value reaches the last value in the range. The [documentation says](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-each):

> The each method can only be used if the **begin** object of the range supports the succ method. A TypeError is raised if the object does not have succ method defined (like Float).

Because Float#succ doesn't make any sense (what's the "next float" from any given float?), iteration through a Float range is undefined. For example, if you wanted to iterate from `1.0`, is the next float 1.1? 1.01? 1.001? This is the same for all Ruby implementations.

If you want to iterate through integers but treat them as floats, just cast them as floats in your block:

```
(1..4).each {|i| p i.to_f }
```

Comment: What if he defines a #succ method for the Float class, just for this purpose?

Comment: It would cause it to work, but I would be extremely wary of unintended side-effects. A #succ for one scenario is not necessarily valid for all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the first question, maybe using `.step(1)` providing `Enumerator` instead of `Range` will be enough for my purposes:

```
> (1..4.0).step.each{ |i| p [i, i.class] }
[1.0, Float]
[2.0, Float]
[3.0, Float]
[4.0, Float]
```